# excel vba - msgbox yes/no reply

Tags: excel, vba

I'm validating users input in userform. I have a msgbox prompt, with yesNo.

If yes is clicked then just continue, if no is clicked I want the user to be able to go back to the userform to change the input/selection.

The code I've used is

```
 iReply = MsgBox(Prompt:="You have selected a month which is not next month. Do you want to continue? ", _
     Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="")
     If iReply = vbNo Then
        UserForm.Show
     End If
```

I get an error for "form already displayed cannot show modally" for
    UserForm.Show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UserForm must be unloaded or hidden before it's loaded again.  Try unloading using:

```
Unload UserForm
```

or hide it using

```
UserForm.Hide
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, but when I did this, it resets all the values input. I just want the user to be able to go back and just change the month value which is a dropdown box which is now doesn't have any values show anymore if I use Unload UserForm.

Comment: You could try hiding it instead, using `UserForm.Hide`